# How to create common method used in Web form as well as Windows form

Tags: c#

I want to create a common method which will use in both web as well as windows form.

Currently I have class like

```
public class Demo
{

   public object getData(object o)
   {
      //Code use by both windows and webform
   }

}
```

I want to use getData(..) method in both windows as well as web form.

how can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. What is your `getData` method will do exactly? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: getData will execute code which is common for both.I have 2 project web and windows so I do not want separate code for both.

Comment: Make a third project that both web and windows projects reference. Put the common code in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve this issue by create Generic method in a class like

```
abstract Class Demo
{

      public object GetData<T>(T obj) where T : objectname;

}
```

now I can pass both web and windows class name in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create class library and use it as a layer (*`.dll`*). use the architecture of Three Tiers/Layers.